# Is there a DNS Blacklist check for Hotmail/Live accounts?

Tags: outlook.com, domain, dns

We have a domain which is having issues sending emails to `@hotmail` and `@live` addresses. If you add the domain to safe senders it goes through no problem at all. However, sending to a random @hotmail/live address will never reach the recipient and will also not send back an NDR. It has all the relevant PTR and SPF records so that shouldn't be an issue.

Is there a blacklist checker for these Microsoft accounts we can use without the palaver of having to go through either their forums or ridiculously large email support form?

Comment: Unfortunately owing to hotmail/outlook/live addresses being free, Microsoft has very little (read: no) support for these addresses. After filling in about 5 online forms, we were assured that we would be contacted by someone on this matter... We weren't...

Yesterday after throwing my toys well and truly out of the pram at them, they have raised a support ticket with MSN Support.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We are having the exact same issue today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange that you don't receive any NDR. You should also check logs of your mail-server.

The process of removing yourself from blacklist is pretty well explained in here: http://www.rackaid.com/resources/hotmail-blacklist-removal/ (this post is quite old, but not much actually changed since that time...)

Be ready that you'll need to spend some amount of time working on removing your domain from blacklist, AFAIK it can only be done manually by some Microsoft team.

Comment: Link points to a 404

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to check but you can get sending fail mail bounce back to sender email address if IP/domain is black listed.

If your server/IP black listed than you can get the domain white listed from Microsoft support link ,

This link really work check here:

[Sender Information for Outlook.com Delivery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&ccsid=635688189955348624&wa=wsignin1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to

1. Check your IP address against known Blacklists http://www.adminkit.net/dnsbl.aspx
2. Check email server or email gateway (anti spam box) log to get the status of message rejected, deferred or delayed.
3. Verify SPF and PTR record.

Try to count number of out going messages to these domains because i have this issue before when internet disconnects and back again. large amount of emails is rejected from some domains because of excessive TCP connections. so my ISP advised to limit number of TCP connections per domain at a time.

Comment: That blacklist check is nice, but which one is the dnsbl that microsoft uses on hotmail?

Comment: Is SPF always needed? TÍ would think this is not always a desired service, i.e. if you want to send with your email through forms on other services

Answer (score -1):

I had an IP blocked in SORBS (http://www.sorbs.net/), it was not possible to send emails to hotmail / live, request the unsubscription from that list, the unsubscription was ok and now I can send emails again to hotmail I think Microsoft uses this list to create its own blacklist.